# Связь платежного терминал и 1с бухгалтерии

Tags: 1с, платежные-терминалы

Здравствуйте! Интересует теория по сабжу.. Может быть кто делал?  
1с-ку 7.7 знаем, прогали.  
Какова логика проведения платежей? Т.е. пользователь вносит деньги - в 1с-ке создается проводка. Я правильно понял?  
Какие применяются интерфейсы (COM, USB...)?  
Может быть сделать сервак, хранящий проводки в СБУБД, к примеру, в MySQL, а затем инициализируемую пользователем синхронизацию с 1с? (тут я и сам разберусь, главное донести данные до MySQL).
Поделитесь пожалуйста имеющимися соображениями.

**добавлено:**  
А что за софт применяется на самих терминалах? Какой бывает? Как работает? Что и куда сохраняет?  
Кстати, в моем случае никаких других операций на терминале не будет! Только оплата счетов по комунальным услугам, на один единственный многоквартирник.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Тем более что софт на терминалах с бухгалтерской программой связан через свой коннектор. Базу можно использовать любую. Самый примитивный терминал (если не принимать деньги) - это легкий клиент, который только умеет запускать браузер. В платежных обычно стоит тоже браузер + обвязка для работы с железом.

Comment: Ну вот, уже кое что.. Идея ясна..